# How to turn off the auto-bold when writing # (pound, hash) in Google Docs

Tags: google-docs

Whenever I use the `#` symbol, the whole line in Google Docs is changed to **bold**.

How can I stop this? I cannot find the feature under Tools > Preferences.

And I'd like to keep the "Automatic substitution" feature.

EDIT

- If I type text followed by `|` ==> it changes to Heading 1
- If I type text followed by `#` ==> it changes to Heading 3

EDIT2

It is related to my keyboard layout, the shortcuts for google docs and the fact that <kbd>AltGr</kbd> is mapped to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>

[image]

Comment: That's not default behavior. Are you doing anything that lets you use Markdown in Google Docs?

Comment: None that I'm aware of.

Comment: I encountered a similar issue where '# ' got replaced with Heading 1. I checked my Tools -> Preferences and there was an option to "Automatically detect Markdown" which was causing the issue. Once I unchecked it, '# ' no longer gets replaced.